# google analytics track multiple downloads

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Trying to add Google analytics tracking to three files within WordPress. My code is placed in the header and it's the following:
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'File Downloads' ,'download', 'click', 'SITE URL HERE/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Application-form-v1-2014.doc', 1);

Had the code up for about a week and no results in the events section of the analytics panel - I've clicked them individually to test.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you send 5 values, while you can send max 4.

The pattern is `_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)`

when opt_value can be only an integer, and opt_nointeraction a boolean. 
In your case you can remove the 'click', and it should work. The 'SITE URL...' will take the space of the label, and "1" of the value.

Comment: Thanks - Have updated the code, will await to see if it works tomorrow.